# check the presence of a class inside a block of another class JS

Tags: javascript, class, dom, child-nodes

I need to check the presence of a class inside a block of another class. Blocks can be many. Nesting can be any. Tell me please what I did wrong. The full code is here https://codepen.io/BK-wmg12/pen/vdjxav
Thank you in advance :-)

```
    <head>
<style>
    .red {
        background-color: red;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<body>
 <div class="test">
   <div class="my">
     <span class="split1">
       Some TEXT1
     </span>

    </div>
   <div class="my">
         <span >
       Some TEXT2
     </span>

    </div>
   <div class="my">
       <span class="split1">
       Some TEXT3
     </span>
<script>
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('my');
    for( var i = 0; i < els.length; i++ ) {
        for( var j = 0; j < els[i].length; j++ ){

            if( !els[i].childNodes[j].classList.contains('split1') ){
                els[i].childNodes[j].classList.add('red');
            }
        }

    }
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi, please provide a specific example about what you need like: "how can I check the existence of the class split1?", cause your actual answer could have different answers depending on what you need exactly. So in order to provide a proper answer for you or other users the question should be more precise ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to check the presence of a class inside a block of another
>   class

Use `querySelector`

```
var isPresent = !!document.querySelector( ".my .split1" )
```

Now iterate all (use `querySelectorAll`)

```
isPresent && Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( ".my .split1" ) ).forEach( function(ele){
   ele.classList.add('red');
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var isPresent = !!document.querySelector(".my .split1")


isPresent && Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".my .split1")).forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.classList.add('red');
})
```

```css
.red 
{
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="my">
    <span class="split1">
       Some TEXT1
     </span>

  </div>
  <div class="my">
    <span>
       Some TEXT2
     </span>

  </div>
  <div class="my">
    <span class="split1">
       Some TEXT3
     </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood the course of your thoughts, but unfortunately this code does not work. Can not read property .add('red');

Comment: @SvetaDashkova Please check the updates, I have added a demo as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically has 2 problems:

1) you need the the length of child nodes

`for( var j = 0; j < els[i].childNodes.length; j++ )`

2) You need to check if the child node is not simple text

`els[i].childNodes[j].nodeName !== "#text"`

or you can even check if it is a span

`els[i].childNodes[j].nodeName === "span"`

Source code as below:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('my');
for( var i = 0; i < els.length; i++ ) {
  console.log(els[i].childNodes)
    for( var j = 0; j < els[i].childNodes.length; j++ ){
    if(els[i].childNodes[j].nodeName !== "#text" && !els[i].childNodes[j].classList.contains('split1') ){
            els[i].childNodes[j].classList.add('red');
        } 
    }

}
```

Codepen for reference:https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/paVwrG

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood my mistake.

Comment: You are Welcome